# Swift: How to reproduce Highlights and Shadows effects from Lightroom?

Tags: swift, cifilter

I'm trying to reproduce Adobe Lightroom Highlights and Shadows in my iOS app. I already tried to use CIHighlightShadowAdjust from CIFilter but it gives me wrong result.

It seems like they change light parts of picture for Highlights and dark parts for Shadows.

**The same question was asked here:** [How to reproduce Highlights and Shadow effects from Adobe Lightroom in iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55017493/how-to-reproduce-highlights-and-shadow-effects-from-adobe-lightroom-in-ios-app) but I don't know how to implement the accepted answer.

How it is possible to change brightness only for dark/light part of picture?

Comment: Did you find any solution how to apply Highlights on image. I m facing same issue. or did you discover how to use this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55017493/how-to-reproduce-highlights-and-shadow-effects-from-adobe-lightroom-in-ios-app.

Comment: Unfortunately no... @MehsamSaeed